# Visual Studio Code error : JavaHome (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, git, github, flutter-dependencies

I followed a [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLtpMqvMgdY&pp=ygURd2VhdGhlciBhcHAgbWlsY2g%3D) to learn how to build a weather app utilizing an API request. There were four packages to be imported.

> _http, geolocator, geofencing and lottie.

I have to upgrade my dart sdk in order to use the lottie package in flutter. I used to get errors one after the other after updating the Dart SDK due to compatibility concerns.

"Unable to find git in your path" was the first issue I encountered. As a result, I reinstalled git. The second issue was with Flutter SDK compatibility, as none of my flutter commands worked.

I attempted to reinstall flutter sdk, jdk, and git.

I arrived here long search and several modifications.

```
The supplied javaHome seems to be invalid. I cannot find the java executable. Tried location: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio1\jbr\bin\java.exe

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              3.1s
Exception: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
PS D:\Flutter_Project\WeatherApp\weather>
```

And my flutter doctor command gives me this:

```
PS D:\Flutter_Project\WeatherApp> flutter doctor
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.13.9, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.22621.2428], locale en-IN)
[√] Windows Version (Installed version of Windows is version 10 or higher)
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[√] Chrome - develop for the web
[X] Visual Studio - develop Windows apps
    X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary to develop Windows apps.
      Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
      Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components
[!] Android Studio (version 2022.2)
    X Unable to find bundled Java version.
[√] VS Code (version 1.84.2)
[√] Connected device (6 available)
[√] Network resources

! Doctor found issues in 2 categories.
PS D:\Flutter_Project\WeatherApp>
```

It would be great if someone could assist. How can this be resolved?

Comment: Please revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. See [ask]. It's tag soup right now. Also, [never link "this" or "here"](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2012/06/links-should-never-say-click-here/#here-conceals-what-users-are-clicking).